# Written in Eclipse unable to run in Oracle JDeveloper

Tags: java, eclipse, jdeveloper

I have an application written by Java in Ecclipse (Kepler), unsuccesfully tried to run in Oracle JDeveloper: especially during running it comes to prompt-input data, but is being unable to move on. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: For a start you can show the problematic code so that we have some chance of determining what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user input in JDeveloper - this might help:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/enabling_user_input_when_runni